# How to populate CheckBox column with Check in DataGridView if record exists?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a DataGridView that only displays 2 columns: Employee Name, and a checkbox called Attended. This is to keep track of employee attendance at safety meetings.

When this DGV is loaded, I would like the employees who have already been marked as having attended to have a check mark in their respective checkboxes.

This is what I tried, but it just checks ALL boxes:

```
private void LoadEmpAttendanceDGV()
{
    string sqlstm = "SELECT EmpID, EmpName FROM dbo.MY_TABLE";
    // Additional code here, which loads the grid.

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        myKey.empID = tempEmpID;
        myKey.trainingID = tempTrainingID;
        myRow = trainingSession.Read(myKey);

        // Check to see if record exists, meaning employee attended meeting.
        if (myRow != null)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                myDataGridView["Attended", j].Value = true;
                // Where "Attended" is the name of my CheckBox column
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can  offer any insight, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: There isn't enough information to figure out where you should be getting the `Attended` values from. What values are there in `myRow` ?

Comment: @AbZy myRow only has empID and trainingID in it. It's simply a linking table between EMPLOYEE and TRAINING.

Comment: You should create a `View` and query that instead.

Comment: @AbZy What would you suggest I put in the view?

Comment: Basically you should link the employee table and training table using the middle table (many to many). and include the attended field. You don't need any looping if you bind the grid to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create tables like this

**SqlServer Code**

```
USE [acc]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmpAttendedTheMeeting](
    [EName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees](
    [EName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
insert into Employees(EName) values('kashif')
insert into Employees(EName) values('sunny')
insert into Employees(EName) values('kamran')

insert into EmpAttendedTheMeeting(EName) values('kashif')
insert into EmpAttendedTheMeeting(EName) values('kamran')
```

**c# Code**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tb = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormatGrid(dataGridView1);
            LoadDg();
        }
        private void FormatGrid(DataGridView dg)
        {
            dg.Columns.Add(tb);
            dg.Columns[0].HeaderText = "EName";
            dg.Columns[0].Width = 199;

            dg.Columns.Add(cb);
            dg.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Attended";
            dg.Columns[1].Width = 69;            
        }
        private void LoadDg()
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("data source=localhost;initial catalog=acc;uid=sa;pwd=emotions");                
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Employees.EName, EmpAttendedTheMeeting.EName from Employees left join EmpAttendedTheMeeting on Employees.EName = EmpAttendedTheMeeting.EName", cn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {           
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1].ToString() == string.Empty ? false : true);
            }
        }   

    }
}
```

Im getting the result in my gridview like this. because sunny is not in EmpAttentendedTheMeeting, his name is unchecked

[image: gridview]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing j to i in the line near the bottom where you set the value

Answer (score 0):

How about catching the existance of the record in the original SQL ?
Something like

SELECT EmpID, EmpName, isnull(attended,0) FROM dbo.MY_TABLE m left outer join attended a on m.EmpID = a.EmpID

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm wrong but this section of the code:

```
        for (int j=0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            myDataGridView["Attended", j].Value = true;
            // Where "Attended" is the name of my CheckBox column
        }
```

Surely sets *every* row to true, doesn't it? You just want to set the specific row to true.

Comment: I have answered him but didn't get any response about my answer. I think he may solve his problem if he ponders on my answer. what about you?